# Send unparsed data in a Node JS request

Tags: node.js, request

I want to send a POST request (for example, with the 'request' module), but I don't find a way of sending **unparsed data***.

***unparsed data** => copied directly from the Chrome dev tool. Something like: *tipo_accion=3&filtro=descarga&fecha=actual*

It would also do the trick some way of translating that string to JSON.

I've tried so far with...

```
var request = require('request');

request.post({ url: 'https://target.com/form/', form: 'tipo_accion=3&filtro=descarga&fecha=actual' },
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body)
    }
);
```

... but it didn't work.

Comment: This one is not a `post` request is a `get` request

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru you mean the one that I posted?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should understand the difference between the request methods [`post`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) and [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET).

The structure that you want to send:
`tipo_accion=3&filtro=descarga&fecha=actual` is telling me that you want to use a `get` request. So the proper code for that will be something like:

```
request(
  'https://target.com/form/&tipo_accion=3&filtro=descarga&fecha=actual',
  function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body)
  },
);
```

But if it is a `post` request then you should use the json format

```
request.post({
  url: 'https://target.com/form/', form: {
    tipo_accion: 3,
    filtro: 'descarga',
    fecha: 'actual'
  },
  function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body)
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'm pretty sure that it's a POST with the form data encoded as _application/x-www-form-urlencoded_

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `form_data` to `string format` and it works for me you can try it :

```
const request = require('request-promise'); 
var j = request.jar()

var data_fom = `a=value_a&b=value_b&c=value_c`
request({ 
        url:"https://target.com/form/",
        jar:j,
        method:"POST",
        resolveWithFullResponse: true,
        form:data_form
    })
```